# Measure of the boundary of the exceptional sets in the Egorov's theorem 

Tags: measure-theory

Let $E\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ be an open set with a zero-measure boundary. Let $f_k$ be a sequence of functions on $E$ such that $f_k\rightharpoonup f$ weakly in $H^1(E)$ and $f_k\to f$ a.e. on $E$ (but $(f_k)$ is not pointwise a.e. bounded).

By the Egorov's theorem, for any $\varepsilon>0$ there is a closed set $A_{\varepsilon}\subset E$ such that $m(E-A_{\varepsilon})\leq\varepsilon$ and $f_k\to f$ uniformly on $A_{\varepsilon}$ ($m$ is the Lebesgue measure).

Question: does it hold

$m(\partial (E-A_{\varepsilon}))=O(g(\varepsilon))$ when $\varepsilon\to0$, where $g(x)\to0$ as $x\to0$?

I know that $m(\partial (E-A_{\varepsilon}))=0$ if the sets $E-A_{\varepsilon}$ are Jordan-measurable, but I don't know if these sets are such. Also, I don't know how to use (if anyhow) the fact that $\nabla f_k$ are uniformly bounded in $L^2(E)$.

Thank you for any comments.

Comment: You can easily create an open set $E$ with the boundary of positive measure. How do you propose to get rid of it by removing a closed subset from $E$? (forget about functions, uniform convergence, etc., just think of this).  

Comment: Are you pointing out that the boundary of an opet set is contained in it's (closed) complement? This is not enough here.


Comment: No, I'm pointing out exactly what I wrote: once you have some ugly chunk in the boundary of $E$, it stays in the boundary of $E\setminus A_\varepsilon$ for any closed subset $A_\varepsilon$ of $E$.

Comment: How does this help to get $m(\partial (E \backslash A_{\varepsilon})) \leq C \varepsilon$?

Comment: It certainly doesn't. On the contrary, it puts an insurmountable obstacle on your way. So you have to lower your expectations and ask for less.

Comment: I am aware of this property in general. What I have specifically is a "nice" $E$ with a zero boundary so the portion of $\partial (E \backslash A_{\varepsilon})$ belonging to $\partial E$ is not a problem.

Comment: Then you should state it this way from the beginning to avoid idiotic comments like mine :). OK, I'll think of this now when it makes more sense.

Comment: Actually, it still doesn't. Suppose that $f_k$ diverge on a dense set. Then $A_\varepsilon$ has no inner points, so it is contained in the boundary of $E\setminus A_\varepsilon$ but it is a set of almost full measure. 

Comment: I was imprecise, sorry. Thank you for your answers. :)

Comment: You are right. Actually, I was hoping the particular construction of the sets $E\setminus A_\varepsilon$ from the proof of Egorov's theorem would be enough. Obviously some additional info about $f_k$ should be utilized, if even this is enough... Thanks anyway.

Comment: You are welcome. The best idea is to ask the question exactly as you have it not trying to generalize or sidestep (unless you have some really good reason to believe that your generalization is the right thing to do). So, if you edit your post and let us know what you are really after, somebody might be able to help :).

Comment: Unfortunately, $H^1$ does not prevent the functions from having dense sets of singularities in dimensions $n>1$, so my last counterexample still stands: $f_n=f+\frac 1n g$ where $g$ is some function with finite $H^1$ norm but a dense set of bad points.

Comment: So this approach does not work. Thanks.